# Plesk not creating a New Database Server

Tags: mysql, database, plesk

I have a windows server where Plesk is installed with php & mySQL by default (from Hosting Provider). When I first got the server I remember I removed mySQL from Control Panel since I didn't need it, but after like one year, I came to a point where I have to create a Wordpress website, and therefore I am needing mySQL again.

Note also that there's two mySQL, one for Plesk (which I didn't uninstall), and another one for our databases (which I uninstalled long ago, but reinstalled later).

I went to Plesk under Database Servers, and I can see there's no Database Servers there... Then I try to  **Add Database Server** with the following settings:
Hostname: localhost
Port: 3306
With Admin Username & Password...

But I am getting the following error:

**Error: A database server with this combination of host address and port number is already registered.**

Please note that this is surely different from the mySQL settings for Plesk since the port is different.

Do you guys have any idea how to resolve this issue? I've been stuck since a few days...

I appreciate your help guys that's urgent!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like inconsistency in plesk database "psa" related to entity of database servers.

Most easy workaround it's to register new database server not as "localhost", but as "127.0.0.1" or some other name which can be resolved to localhost or other port.

Another workaround it's to look into psa database via "%plesk_bin%\dbclient.exe" --direct-sql --sql="select * from databaseservers".